# .NET WPF Diagrams/Graphs

Tags: wpf, graph, components, diagram

I need WPF component (beter if it will be free) for easy drawing such process graphics like on the image. Can you give an advice what to use? Thanks.

[image: http://img842.imageshack.us/img842/3444/40560107.png]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end i have used [WPF toolkit](http://wpf.codeplex.com/releases/view/40535). Its free and with few customizations can be used to draw such diagrams as i needed. Example of using is [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/LineChartWPF11252009200659PM/LineChartWPF.aspx).